# What's the correct name for this type of bath and shower mixer tap?

Tags: shower, bathtub, taps

I'm looking for a way to find a certain type of tap but I'm not native English and have no idea of the terminology, or even what I need exists...

Wall has 2 pipe endings, 15cm apart.
I need one big lever to mix both hot and cold (ceramic thing?).
Output is 1 tub filling normal flow.
Another output is to handheld shower head.

The most important is that the **switch between the 2 outputs should NOT be automatic**. I've seen those with 2 different controls (one hot, one cold) where the switch is manual. But I haven't seen any solution with manual switch that also has 1 big lever for mixing.
[image]

The reason is that the automatic is very fiddly for me. I almost exclusively use the handheld shower output and I hardly ever want the tub filling output (but it's nice to have). I don't wish to fiddle every day with the pressure-sensitive switch, since it all defaults to tub-filling mode as far as I know.

Comment: The "manual valve" is a type of diverter valve.  Typical bath faucet diverters are held in place by the water flow that they are diverting.  This is actually considered a feature that the shower won't be automatically on for the next water flow.

Comment: I happen to dislike that feature :)

Comment: In an apartment I had in college, I wrapped the shaft with silver duct tape to hold it up.

Comment: If I were to buy a diverter valve-less design.. Does such device exists that splits the single showerhead output to 2 outputs with a manual switch? Which is a screw-on addon maybe.

Comment: What kind of water heater do you have--tank or tankless?

Comment: Tank, we call it boiler.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google 'bar mixing valve' or 'thermostatic bar mixing valve'.

The one you picture looks to me like it is not thermostatic nor pressure balancing. It has no 'anti-scald' protection. Anti-scald valves are now required for a shower in nearly every plumbing code as far as I know.

The bar mixing valve type has the advantage that the entire valve is outside the wall, enabling repair or complete replacement without disturbing the wall.

Comment: A downvote is OK with me, I will sometime pipe up on a question that I'm not sure about just to get the discussion started, but I wonder what is wrong with my answer here. Is it false that all codes now require a thermostatic mixing valve for the shower? Or is something else wrong with my answer?

Comment: It's not me who's downvoting. I still haven't found the name for this, but I found a brand. They add a "secret" state to the switch that lets the user lock in the flow on the showerhead, and not only rely on the water pressure keep it on the showerhead.

Comment: The dropping of the diverter when the water is turned off allows the water in the shower pipe to drain promptly into the tub. If the diverter is locked in the shower position, won't the trapped water slowly drip and keep the tub wet for hours? I have an in-wall diverter and after every shower I manually turn the diverter to the intermediate position so the shower drains promptly. Have I been putting unnecessary wear on the diverter for decades?

Comment: @JimStewart I downvoted the question - It isn't an answer as it doesn't answer the question and provides incorrect information. It's the kind of thing that should have been asked in a comment, not stated in an answer. FWIW the above is definitely not a bar mixer (it's a bath/shower mixer tap) and you've talked about codes without asking about location (which is probably the UK where an anti-scald device isn't necessary except on new builds...which wasn't asked about anyway).

Comment: @Niall, are all shower and bath/shower mixer taps in the UK and in Europe *external* to the wall? In the US they were traditionally internal to the wall and when I became aware of "bar mixing valves" I assumed (it seems wrongly) that was the term for a mixing valve which was external to the wall and had space between the back of the valve and the wall. In the UK when one *replaces* a bath/shower mixer tap do some regulatory authorities require that the new tap be thermostatic anti-scald or is one allowed to replace with the same type which has no anti-scald protection?

Comment: @JimStewart No, but external is much more common. Bar mixers are specifically the ones that are bar shaped - this is a bar mixer  https://bit.ly/2PPSh5q but this isn't https://bit.ly/2Gx7YiR . The tap that OP posted is a very common feature in bathrooms, though now it's mostly as a back-up to electric showers/for cost-cutting ( eg. https://bit.ly/2EuqANw )  which are used  instead of mixers as many/most homes have heating/plumbing systems which give very poor performance with mixers. Mixers are used where the system suits, they give much better performance than electric showers.

Comment: @JimStewart  Anti-scald devices are required on new-builds and new bathrooms(when the use of a room is changed to become a bathroom) but not for any replacement/refurbishment in an existing bathroom.

Comment: @Niall, I am surprised at that because, if I understand correctly, with the UK/European style valves there is no demo of the wall required to change the shower valve. There is a standard spacing of 15 cm between the two stub outs insuring that the latest design will fit the same stub out pipes. In the UK is the temperature of the hot water normally not hot enough to scald? I can imagine that remote controlled central tankless heaters or point of use tankless heaters could be controlled to deliver water of say 43 deg C (110 F) so that scalding would be prevented at the source.

Comment: @JimStewart 1st bit - not sure we're on the same page? Yes "exposed" mixers are more common, where mixers are used(as opposed to taps with mixers/other options), yes the spacing is standard. 2nd bit - It's purely that the UK can be very slow to adopt building standards and they generally don't consider this a big deal - there was no requirement until 2010. Re your suggestion - that temp. would be considered too low to kill bacteria in the system.

Comment: @Niall, IIUC, it is only with a tank water heater that one is concerned about getting a high enough temperature to kill Legionella. With a tankless WH, the low volume of the piping on the hot side of the water heater, the high linear flow rate,  and the residual chlorine are sufficient to inhibit and remove any bacteria. In fact my wife and I have a minimal central tankless WH (undersized Bosch natural gas fired) and the temp of the output is no more than 120 F (49 C). Of course, the fact that I tolerate such a system does not mean it meets public health standards.